# Material cell won't fully change background color

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design

I have an Angular Material `mat-table` that contains a selection box in the `mat-header-cell` and `mat-cell` definitions. I want the background of the header to be red with a white foreground. I defined a class, but only one-third of the cell (the middle) is colored (I'm sorry I don't know how to add a picture to show). I tried adding the background color inline to the `td` cell, but that didn't change anything.

This is the html:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
        [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

And the SCSS:

```
.mat-header-cell {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: white;
}
```

Can someone tell me if I'm missing something? Maybe the cell's padding is causing all the white around the cell?

Edit: I should add that I'm not an HTML developer, so I only have a basic understanding of styles!

Comment: Can you please provide a [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the scss lines to

```
.mat-header-row {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  .mat-header-cell{
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Try to provide a slackblitz demo if this don't fix the problem

Comment: That did it! But can you tell me why?

Comment: I cant say much without seeing the whole code. It may be due to some other style giving .mat-header-cell a margin or something. You were changing only individual header cell background, but the header have its own background color